# We need consistency in the various records tags

Tags: discussion, tags

As expected, our tag list is full of tags describing different types of records:

- [records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/records)
- [death-record](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-record)
- [birth-record](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birth-record)
- [vital-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vital-records)
- [census-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/census-records)
- [military-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military-records)
- [marriage-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriage-records)
- [court-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/court-records)
- [land](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/land) and [deed](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deed)
- [death-certificates](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-certificates)
- [birth-certificates](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birth-certificates)
- [bmd-certificates](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bmd-certificates)

How can we make this more consistent?

Comment: FYI, I'm waiting to act on this until we get pro-tem moderators so that they can create the tag synonyms; otherwise we run the risk of the tags being used again.

Comment: JustinY, it's possible to create tag synonyms now, with enough reputation.

Answer (score 7):

The "certificates" tags should become synonyms for the "records" tags:

- [death-certificates](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-certificates) -> [death-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-records)
- [birth-certificates](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birth-certificates) -> [birth-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birth-records)
- [bmd-certificates](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bmd-certificates) -> [vital-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vital-records)
- [marriage-certificates](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriage-certificates) -> [marriage-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriage-records)

[marriage-certificates](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriage-certificates) doesn't actually exist, but we should create it as a synonym for [marriage-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriage-records) anyways.

Comment: I prefer records, too.

Comment: The tag wiki's are very different -- e.g. for death-certificates (very specific) and death-record (very general). I'm concerned that we might lose the value of the specificity. A death certificate is different to (say) a burial entry in a parish register, or the probate of a will, or a post-mortem report or an obituary in a newspaper, but they're all death records. I think this needs a little more discussion.

Answer (score 3):

All of the tags should end in "s".

- [death-record](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-record) -> [death-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-records)
- [birth-record](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birth-record) -> [birth-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birth-records)

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the general "records" and always require a "type" prefix.

Comment: How about one category "general-records"

Comment: @genej - better to specify than to generalize. Misc-records is better if it doesn't fit into other categories.

Comment: We do all long for the perfect balance between consistency and accuracy. It's a little like setting up source types, itn's it. Once you get beyond birth, marriage, death, the categories might seem easy, especially if you do a lot of work with one or two record providers. Notions will be more challenging across all users. 

There will be also questions that involve more than one record type/record group. Maybe for this group, you could have some kind of "multiple-records?" Whatever you decide to do is fine with me.

Comment: @GeneJ when a question involves multiple types of records it should include all of the relevant tags. If that adds up to more than 5 then I would choose the most important. Plus, chances are if it involves more than 5 and they're all "important" then the question is asking too much.

Comment: I wouldn't disagree, except that records are location and sometimes langage centric, too. It doesn't matter to me what you decide to do. Those classifying source types run into this too.

Answer (score 1):

[land](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/land) and [deed](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deed) should become [land-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/land-records), perhaps with a synonym created for [deeds](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deeds) -> [land-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/land-records).