# How can we pluralize tags?

Tags: support, tags

When trying to add an 's' to [death-record](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-record) tags, as we [previously discussed](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1466/we-need-consistency-in-the-various-records-tags), I was shown the following error message:

> Creating the new tag [death-records] is not allowed since the tag [death-record] already 
>   exists. If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta.

So... how are we supposed to change this? If we can't create the new tag, is there a way we can edit the tag? Does it require mod powers to do this?

Comment: Ha! So now will the meta-miracle-man now please step forward!

Comment: Trogdor the Burninator, at your service.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use "tag synonyms" to effectively retag the questions, but was not successful. The tag has to be in the system before it can be proposed. (Note: My attempt probably would have failed anyway, because I might not have enough upvotes on questions so tagged.)

[image]

Comment: This is precisely why we need good people to volunteer to act as a site moderator. With a diamond by your name, you would be able to solve this problem. ;)

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

1. Make a list of all questions with [death-record](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-record). We don't want the tags to get mixed up in the whole process.
2. Flag one of the questions with [death-record](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-record). Select `it needs ♦ moderator attention > other`. In the box, ask the devs to burninate [death-record](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-record). Include a link to https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1467/56 so the devs realize this community consensus. *Note, AFAIK, only devs can burninate tags. However, the flag should go to the devs anyhow because mods have not yet been appointed here.*
3. Retag all the questions from your list [death-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-records).

### *Disclaimer*

*I've never done this myself, but it's supposed to work. You might want to ask the devs to retag the questions with [death-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-records) also (rather than doing it yourself).*