# Seeking assistance creating tag-synonym [kingdom-of-norway]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

As below, suggesting tag synonyms requires both 1250 rep and an answer score of 5 or more on questions so tagged. As below, my tag synonym suggestion failed today for the reasons described here.

Sigh. Hoping one of the moderators will create the tag synonym described below. Thanks.

Today I created the tag [norway](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norway) and set out to suggest the tag synonym, "kingdom-of-norway. The latter attempt returned an error because even though *my question* tagged  [norway](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norway) had an upvote score of 10, I do not have an *answer* score of 5 or more on questions so tagged.

> [image: sdkf;];

See also the related [meta post/answer about synonyms](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1493/7) on the question "[How can we pluralize tags?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/how-can-we-pluralize-tags)"

StackExchange requirements for suggesting tag synonyms seem too restrictive. A more reasonable permissions requirement would allow suggestions by a user with necessary rep who has a question *or* answer score of at least 5 (on the tag).

Comment: My only concern is that the "Norway" does not always refer to the Kingdom of Norway. The Kingdom of Norway was only founded in 1814. My opinion is to not have a Norway tag at all. Rather, we'll have three separate tags: [Kalmar Union], [Kingdom of Denmark], and [Kingdom of Norway].

Comment: I'm not sure how complex you want this to be, Luke. In this case, my ancestors came from a country that is today known as the Kingdom of Norway. They immigrated to a country that is today known as the United States of America. If the master tag for the latter country is "united-states," than I suggest the master tag for the former should be "norway."

Comment: @π Luke , GeneJ I'd keep this simple. Norway is a well-understood geographical unit, and ought to be the master tag. Details in the question ought to make it clear what time period is relevant, and the detail in the tag wiki can clarify how the political (and boundary) arrangements changed with time. So I don't think we need kingdom-of-norway at all.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl I understand now and I agree with you. Time periods should be denoted by century tags, not separate place tags.

Comment: GeneJ, let us know if you feel strongly that Kingdom-of-Norway is needed. I guess if people are likely to use it in preference to norway, we should create the synonym.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl. Thank you for asking, but if I have a question, it is probably broader than this meta; more about the intentions for using tag-synonyms. I suspect you would both agree that in this discussion, the bar is set pretty high for qualifying tag synonyms (ala, something far more than "aka"). Perhaps ACProctor will post the link here to one or more of C.P.G. Grey's fun and interesting videos about places and the names we give them.